# Centos 7 unable to increase partition, found device with duplicate

Tags: centos7, lvm

I was trying to increase the `usr` and the `var` partition on one of our server but i have this warning (see image below) when I type `pvs`

and later on it throw a lot of warnings and an error when I try to extended the partition

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?

`lvs` result is:

```
WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/md3
WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/sdb3
WARNING: Disabling lvmetad cache which does not support PVs
WARNING: Scan found duplicate PVs
WARNING: Not using lvmetad because cache update failed
WARNING: Not suing device /dev/md3 for PV .....
WARNING: PV ... prefer device /dev/sda3 because of previous preference
WARNING: Device mismatch detected for vg00/urs with is accessing /dev/md3 instead of /dev/sda3, /dev/sda3
WARNING: Device mismatch detected for vg00/var with is accessing /dev/md3 instead of /dev/sda3, /dev/sda3
WARNING: Device mismatch detected for vg00/home with is accessing /dev/md3 instead of /dev/sda3
LV   VG    Attr       LSize
home vg00  -wi-ao---- 5GB
usr  vg00  -wi-ao---- 6GB
var  vg00  -wi-ao---- 105GB
```

`df -h` result is:

```
Filesystem                  Mounted on
/dev/md1                    /
devtmpfs                    /dev 
tmpfs                       /dev/shm
tmpfs                       /run
tmpfs                       /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr        /usr
none                        /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-home       /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-var        /var
tmpfs                       /run/user/10010
```

`lvmdiskscan` result is:

```
WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/md3
WARNING: found device with duplicate /dev/sdb3
WARNING: Disabling lvmetad cache which does not support PVs
WARNING: Scan found duplicate PVs
WARNING: Not using lvmetad because cache update failer
/dev/vg00/usr
/dev/md1
/dev/vg00/var
/dev/sda2
/dev/vg00/home
/dev/md3           LVM phisical volume
/dev/sdb2
3 disks
3 partitions
0 LVM phisical volume whole disks
1 LVM phisical volume
```

and the `blkid` results

```
/dev/md1: LABEL="root" UUID="6edddd0e-a52c-45ff-8ece-24e93448a69e" TYPE="ext3" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="e5096346-4290-310d-1f51-fb8978ee93fe" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr: LABEL="usr" UUID="5a86bc5c-f160-4353-83cd-d44703842676" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="a0045011-687b-f338-1f51-fb8978ee93fe" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="6064f77c-72bc-42f9-9dfe-584ec9d74385" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="bf72d033-bc14-4780-b19f-d2f87ef40b7c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="e5096346-4290-310d-1f51-fb8978ee93fe" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="a0045011-687b-f338-1f51-fb8978ee93fe" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md3: UUID="WofUlL-4B5d-Lt97-R4ml-fj7f-kzch-IWcfLn" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg00-var: LABEL="var" UUID="3c9e5ddf-6933-40a0-b8d4-a6f877f8c228" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/vg00-home: LABEL="home" UUID="902855cd-8f75-4241-8307-f8f4aa43fb0d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Seeing the rest of the LVM configuration and all your partition and mounts would be helpful. Also, posting text instead of screenshots would be nice.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider sorry for the image, I've update my question with more info about the server config

Comment: Also paste the output of the `blkid` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I contacted my provider as the install image itself is coming from them and they told me that was a problem with some Centos 7 distros.

Here is how they fixed it:

Firstly I made a backup of your lvm.conf file:

```
# cp /etc/lvm/lvm.conf /etc/lvm/lvm.conf.bak
```

We edited the configuration file to filter correctly

```
# vi /etc/lvm/lvm.conf

filter = [ "a|/dev/md.*|", "r/.*/" ]
```

I then ran `vgscan` and `pvscan` to confirm issue has been resolved.

It is recommended that you restart the server before performing the LVM.

Comment: I have yet to find a server provider which knows how to install the OS correctly. I always wipe their stuff and do the installation myself.

Comment: sadly I cannot reimage the server with a custom image they allow just to install their own images